# Where get list of all bitcoin data store changes?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain-fork

I want to create my own database with bitcoin transactions, blocks and etc. I understand that bitcoin changes some times, added segwit and other. For support this thing i need remastered storage, create all needed columns. Any body have list with blocks in which storage has changed? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such changes at specific blocks.

Segregated witness changed the definition of what data exists in a transaction, but it did that retroactively for every transaction. So, from the perspective of a post-segwit node, *every* transaction has an input witness for each of its inputs. For old transactions that witness is just empty. From the perspective of pre-segwit nodes, nothing changed, because they don't know, care, or see the input witnesses (other nodes will drop the witness when relaying to pre-segwit nodes).

So really the choice for you is whether you want to present information as seen by post- or pre-segwit nodes. Both are perfectly consistent and meaningful, and neither needs any special casing of transition from one format to another.

There are also no other changes like this since Bitcoin's release in 2009, as far as I know.